# How to get page number of selected row in AG grid react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pagination, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I am using AG grid react in my project with group rows functionality. But I am having an issue, when table load then all rows remain on first page but when I open a group then few rows move to next page because I have set pagination size to 10 and I cannot remove it.

I want to get the page number on which my selected row is present.